# World of Warcraft Stopped Downloading Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wine, games

I found out how to get *WoW* running on Ubuntu using *Wine 1.5* and am able to play it (albeit somewhat slow, but that's mostly due to my hardware). It was downloading just fine and I could play without any errors.

But now that it has reached `85.5%`. It refuses to download any more. It was stopped at 84.5 but I reloaded the Launcher multiple times and it moved another `1%`.

I don't know why it stopped; the only thing I did was close the Launcher to resume it later (which hadn't caused problems until 84.5% downloaded). Everything loads and it seems like it is just lagging (the download speed wont show up and start downloading the game again).

Anyone know what I can do?

(Not using dual-boot with Windows, just straight Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Just remove your current wine version and install the last one 1.7. This should do the trick.